# vue.js hyphened attribute not interpreted correctly in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've defined a custom modal component in Vue.js which works. However, I've stumbled upon a bug that I'd like to understand a little better. You see, my modal is a simple confirm dialog with Yes/No buttons. Thanks to Vue's templating features, I was able to set it up so I can pretty much reuse my component for every confirm dialog in my application. You see, in order to make this work, I had to turn the "ID" attribute into a parameter. Here's the code:

```
Vue.component('modal-confirm', {
        props: ['message', 'mod_id'],
        template:`
        <div class="modal fade" :id="mod_id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header alert-primary">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-primary"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Confirmation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">@{{ message }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <modal-confirm-btn etiquette="Oui" valeur="true" url="{{ url('/api/reportsrenew/deliverReport') }}" v-on:modal_confirm="modalConfirm"></modal-confirm-btn>
                        <modal-confirm-btn etiquette="Non" valeur="false" url="{{ url('/api/reportsrenew/deliverReport') }}" v-on:modal_confirm="modalConfirm"></modal-confirm-btn>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `,
        methods:{
            emit: function(valeur, url){
                this.$emit('modal_confirm',  valeur, url ); 
            }
        },
        components: {
            'modal-confirm-btn': {
            template: '<button v-on:click="emit" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary">@{{ etiquette }}</button>',
            props:['etiquette', 'valeur', 'url'],
            methods:{
                emit: function(){
                    this.$emit('modal_confirm',  this.valeur, this.url ); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, as you can see, in "props", I've defined the "mod_id" property which I use inside my template. However, if I try to use "mod-id" as a property name, I get the error message

> Property or method "mod" is not defined on the instance but referenced
>   during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the
>   data option.

I'd just like to know why hyphens are not allowed in property names for this specific use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a dash in a property definition in Vue, when Vue adds the property to the Vue in a camelCased version. In your case, `mod-id` becomes `modId` on the Vue.

When you then try to reference `mod-id` in the template, Vue interprets

```
:id="mod-id"
```

as the javascript expression, `mod - id`, or subtracting a variable called `id` from a variable called `mod`.

You have no property called `mod` on your Vue which results in your error.

So technically, Vue allowed you to define the property with a dash, but it changed it underneath you to the camelCased version because it is adding that property to the Vue. In javascript, you typically will not have properties on objects that include a dash. You *can* have them, but you have to enclose them in quotes and you have to dereference them using an indexer (ie. `this['mod-id']`). It doesn't make sense to write all the framework code such that it would have to deal with that edge case, so Vue just converts them to camelCased.